# How to omit some code when doing bitbucket merge

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge

Is it possible to omit some code when merging and pushing changes to any secondary branch?

For example, in one branch you are keeping UI changes, while in other branch you are keeping Code changes. This way if I want to skip some code at the time of compare then is it possible? Or there is a different approach to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the why-would-you-want-to-do-that answer.  Perhaps someone will address your how question directly]

I see that (keeping different code on different branches) as a mis-use of branching. You can handle that as two different repos or as a monorepo of both projects.  I'd suggest looking at the various references on monorepos and also on popular git workflow strategies.

Comment: Any example on how to manage that when we are handling or playing with both separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to omit some code (specific commits) when you are merging, you could use `git cherry-pick` instead of `git merge` but cherry-pick is not a good practice for all the time to use.

If you need to separate your UI code and back-end code, I would recommend to use two git repositories or use [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) feature.

Comment: Any example on how to manage that when we are handling or playing with both separately.

Comment: Are the front-end (UI) and back-end decoupled. And are you using any pakage management tool (eg: npm, web-pack, maven,..)

Could you please share with me that code structure of your project?

Comment: Basically we are developing an application Mobile version (iOS/`Swift`, Android/`Java`) and also a Web version in `React.js`. We like to keep shell/UI version separate so we can always improve the UI separately (in separate branch), so the development team can take it and do any integration into it.

Comment: As I understood, You just need to keep UI related changes separate from other code changes on your mobile/web app.

So ideal approach would be keep UI changes in separate branch and once you need to integrate new UI changes, you may use git cherry-pick. 

When you cherry picking, if there are more than one commits, you should cherry-pick first older commit.

"Keep separate repositories" approach would be better If your code structure like below.
*API (back-end code)
*Mobile App (iOS, Android)
* Webb App